# Angular 8 Material table highlight a row on click and kep the background color after click on other row

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, mat-table

I look for a simple way to save the color of a row, after clicking on another row

My mat-row

```
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['favicon', 'name', 'quality', 'created_at', 'report', 'edit']" 
 (click)="selectedRow = selectedRow === row ? null : row" [ngClass]="{ 'selected': row === selectedRow }">
```

.ts

```
selectedRow
```

css

```
.selected {
  background-color: red!important;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #e4f0ec;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

> The problem: After click in some row, the background change to red
>   (this is OK) but after click on other row, the preview (red) row, lost thei background color.

Expected result:
All clicked rows need to save the red color, or EVEN BETTER - get some other color (to make the difference - row - selected row - visited row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivan, you can not use an unique variable, you need use an array or a new property of your elements. Imagine you call this new variabe "selected"

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      [class.selected]="element.selected"
      (click)="element.selected= !element.selected">
</tr>
```

See that your "elements" can has properties that not show in the table

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Angular Material components that they are wrapped in many style classes and it's hard to overwrite it. Although there is some solutions which I discovered how to overwrite `mat-*` styles. I will give you an examples:

### 1. Define style class in global style.css file

First you need to discover which classes is used for your action. It could be done with development tools in Google Chrome or other tools.
Then in global styles file (`style.css` or `style.scss`...) define that class style.
**i.e.** (my case):

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label, .mat-datepicker-toggle {
    color: white !important;
}
```

---

### 2. Define style class using ::ng-deep or >>>

***(deprecated)***
In your component style class define same discovered `mat-*` style classes using `::ng-deep` or `>>>` prefix.
**i.e.** (my case):

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label, .mat-datepicker-toggle {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Although this solution is deprecated and I didn't found replacement for that to overwrite styles in component styles file.

---

### 3. Use custom style class without view encapsulation

First you need to set encapsulation parameter/flag in your component. Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-element',
  templateUrl: './my-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-element.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyElementComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

Then you can write your own style classes for Angular Material components. 
It might be that Material components will not look as before (real Material components)

---

> ***It's not an exact solution for your problem, but direction for finding your own solution***